# Specify for in loop type

Tags: xcode, swift, for-loop, for-in-loop

I would like to specify the type for *item* in the for in loop below.

```
for item in items {
}
```

Currently it is `AnyObject` but I would like to set it to `NSString`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is a common problem. The solution is to cast:

```
for item in items as [NSString] {
```

It is perhaps a little surprising that you have to cast the array (`items`) rather than explicitly declaring the type of the loop variable (`item`). But that's the syntax, and you'll quickly get used to it.

Comment: And see the discussion of `for ... in` loops in my new Swift tutorial: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch05.html#_for_loops

Comment: I would just advise you to think twice about casting down to NSString. This is rarely what's wanted. You should probably cast to down to `[String]` instead.

Comment: Use the optional form of the type cast operator (as?) when you are not sure if the downcast will succeed.